# toggle menu triggers all elements with class

Tags: javascript

So I'm very new to this and I can't figure out how to stop this behavior. When I click one of the items with the toggleshow class it triggers all the .subnav elements to toggle their class list. How do I change this to only effect the clicked element.

```
const toggleMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleShow');
const subnav = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav');

// The below works but on ALL subnav...
toggleMenu.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    subnav.forEach((menuItem) => {
      menuItem.classList.toggle('active');
      console.log('Click!');
    });
  });
});
```

I’ll post the html and CSS that is tied to this tonight thanks to those who commented and gave some guidance. First post I thought it was best to limit the scope but after reading about a minimum viable snippet it makes more sense what’s needed.

Comment: Please go read [mre]. Questions like this should include all the necessary information - in this case that would be at least, what your HTML structure actually looks like.

Comment: You are currently selecting _all_ elements with that class across the whole document - you need to limit this to the relevant parent/ancestor element. `querySelectorAll` can not only be called on document, but on _any_ element node as well - in which case it will only return descendants of that node.

Comment: (And you will of course also have to add something that removes the `active` class from whatever element might currently have it.)

Comment: Where is your html fragments?